Почему не "нн" в слове
Почему в слове "шизофреник" одна "н", ведь "н" уже была в основе производящего слова: шизофреНи-я - шизофрен-ик.


В данном случае используется следующая схема словообразования: шизофрен/и/я — шизофрен/ик, суффикс -ИК, усечение основы на -ИЙ.

Значение — лицо по занятиям, по сфере науки, по каким нибудь свойствам характера или болезни.
Сравнить: химия — химик, меланхолия — меланхолик.

Суффикс -НИК также может использоваться при образовании сущ. от сущ.: путь — путник, целина — целинник, измена — изменник.

Значение — лицо, отнесенное к какому-нибудь предмету, занятию, кругу деятельности.
Материал из Толкового словаря словообразовательных единиц Т. Ф. Ефремовой.

Почему здесь не использовался "ник"?

От основы зависит и от значения. Для слов на ИЯ используется ИК: химия – химик.

Простое есть орфографическое правило: если основа содержит "н", то она должна удваиваться.

Орфографическое правило не самодостаточно, оно следует из морфемного состава слов. Основа в русском языке не удваивается  (такое явление есть в англ. языке), но происходит удвоение в том случае, если основа на Н и суффикс на Н.  Суффикс НИК фактически является сложным суффиксом Н  + ИК, например: лес - (лесной) - лесник. Н по сути суффикс промежуточного прилагательного, а ИК основной суффикс существительного, сравнить:  старый – старик. Но в нашем случае промежуточное прилагательное не нужно, так как основа усекается при словообразовании (суффикс И меняется на ИК). Другая модель.

Шизофрени́я. Это психическое заболевание, характеризующееся расстройством восприятия окружающего мира, образовано на базе греческих skizo — «расщепляю» и phren — «разум».  Фактически образования обоих слов происходит от греческой основы phren

А как же "малина - малинник"?

Малина - (малинный кустарник) - малин/ник, сложный суффикс НИК  + основа МАЛИН-,   Все по правилам.  У Ефремовой написано, что ИК присоединяется к основам, не осложненным суффиксом. Здесь, вероятно, ИН тоже суффикс, существительного,  хотя мы его не выделяем.    Мали́на. Слово, окончательно не раскрытое этимологами. Связывают его с нашим корнем «мал-»: малиновая ягода состоит из многих «малых» ягодок-зернышек. Другие видят в нем древний индоевропейский корень, означавший «синий» или «черный» (греческое «ме́лас» — «черный»),

В общем, в этой теме надо помнить, что есть два суффикса ИК и НИК, а проверить лучше по словам без удвоения НН.  ИК для основ прилагательных прил  - сущ, а НИК для основ существительных сущ - сущ.  Но сущ на ИЯ имеют суффикс ИК, так как основа усекается до чистого корня.
